# Connect Win NT and Vista via switch

Tags: networking, switch

I have an old NT Server and a laptop running Vista and I need to get files off of the NT server onto the laptop. I have a little Netgear switch and was wondering how to allow them to talk to each other.

Each computer is setup to 'Workgroup'. I have the IPs for each like this:
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2

Do i need to do anything to the DNS settings? Is there anything else I need to do?

Chopps

Comment: DNS is a protocol used for resolving domain name queries to IP addresses, when you are connecting via IP you never need DNS settings.  You will only need more information than a configured IP when you are using computers in different subnets. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork subnets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your vista laptop, just open the "run" command and type in `\\192.168.1.1\c$` (assuming .1 is your server and .2 is your vista machine).

When prompted for username and password, just enter a valid username on the NT4 box, including the computername of the NT4 computer, like this: NT4SERVER\Administrator (assuming the server name is "NT4SERVER" and you connect with the administrator password.

This should give you access to the c drive on the server.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, there may be interference from the Vista firewall.  Making sure the network location is set to private should be sufficient.  See this guide http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/124812-network-location-type-change.html

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do anything with DNS. Make sure "File & Printer Sharing" and "Client for Microsoft Networks" is bound to the NIC on each machine. Make sure that the "Server" and "Workstation" and "RPC" services are running on each machine. You should be able to access the NT server from the Vista machine by using a UNC path and passing credentials that the NT server recognizes (local user account on NT server).

\ip_address_of_nt_server\c$

Comment: I guess the site stripped the double back slash from my answer. Make sure you access the UNC path using a double back slash at the beginning.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash.  It looks like 3 backslashes in a row is sufficient although the normal 4 backslashes to display 2 works also.  Watch your preview while typing and you will see the result.